# In tomcat, database connection is closed in between partial excecution

Tags: database, tomcat

In tomcat, database connection is closed in between partial excecution, getting java.net.Connection: refused to connect. Exception is not consistent on any operation, it is thrown between different interval. Can anyone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IF OBJECT_ID('sysGenerateInsert','P') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROC sysGenerateInsert
    PRINT 'sysGenerateInsert SP successfully dropped'
END 
GO

CREATE PROC sysGenerateInsert(@TblName varchar(128))
AS
BEGIN
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Purpose: Generates INSERT statement for the given table 
    --          * Multiline insert
    --          * Copy the generated Script and remove the last comma
    --            and execute
    --
    -- Usage:   EXEC sysGenerateInsert 'TableName'
    -- 
    -- Created By: Guruprasad    On: 3-Jan-2010
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE #ColumnMetaData (
        Id      INT IDENTITY (1,1), 
        IsChar  INT, 
        ColName VARCHAR(128)
    )

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TblName)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('No columns found for table %s or Table not exist', 16,-1, @TblName)
    RETURN
END

INSERT  #ColumnMetaData (IsChar, ColName)
SELECT CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END IsChar,
       COLUMN_NAME     ColName
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = @TblName
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

DECLARE @InsertIntoStmt VARCHAR(MAX),
        @InsertIntoData VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @InsertIntoStmt = 'SELECT '' INSERT INTO ' + @TblName + ' ( '
SELECT @InsertIntoData = 'SELECT ''(''+' 

SELECT  @InsertIntoStmt = @InsertIntoStmt + ColName + ','
FROM    #ColumnMetaData

SELECT @InsertIntoData =    @InsertIntoData
        + ' CASE WHEN ' + ColName + ' IS NULL '
        +   ' THEN ''NULL'' '
        +   ' ELSE '
        +     CASE WHEN IsChar = 1 
                   THEN  ''''''''' + ' + ColName + ' + ''''''''' 
                   ELSE 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),' + ColName + ')' 
              END
        + ' END + '','' + '
FROM    #ColumnMetaData

SELECT @InsertIntoStmt = LEFT(@InsertIntoStmt,LEN(@InsertIntoStmt)-1) + ' )  VALUES ''' 
SELECT @InsertIntoData = LEFT(@InsertIntoData,LEN(@InsertIntoData)-8) + ' + ''),'' FROM ' + @tblName

EXEC (@InsertIntoStmt + ' UNION ALL ' + @InsertIntoData)

DROP TABLE #ColumnMetaData
```

END
go

PRINT 'sysGenerateInsert SP successfully created'